# Post image to facebook using graph api

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I am using facebook graph api to post image and message to facebook. I have taken help from Raywenderlich tutorial. It was working fine before last two weeks. But now it creating issue for me. I am getting all the facebook profile information.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"];



            data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);






       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"];

    NSString *message = [couponInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"offerTitle"];

    message = [message stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];

    NSString *offerSlogan = [couponInfoDictionary objectForKey:@"offerSlogan"];

    message = [message stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",offerSlogan]];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setData:data forKey:@"file"];
    [request setPostValue:message forKey:@"message"];
    [request setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendToPhotosFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestError:)];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];



- (void)sendToPhotosFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"response string before photo id %@",responseString);

    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *photoId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"Photo id is: %@", photoId);

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?access_token=%@", photoId, [_accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSLog(@"sendToPhotosFinished = %@",urlString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *newRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookPhotoFinished:)];

    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];

}
```

But when i posting the image, It giving me error

```
{"error":{"message":"Error validating application.","type":"OAuthException"}}

 Photo id is: (null)
 sendToPhotosFinished = https://graph.facebook.com/(null)?access_token=ABACesEZBKr3gBALqa4yE2QAnJbNbGvQKa9iCm53GmTwHQYoyaxqAqmdLj0gw9uWCbyhP5sV7N6uZBjaFDpD6v6G1C7GcZCjvcZBPqt7b1ZAxKtDvepN8c&expires_in=4778


 Got Facebook Photo: {"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

I have spent my three days to resolve it. But still not getting any idea..how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

use this @"117795728310/photos" insted of me/photos

In the third line of your above code ,

Answer (score 0):

Photo id is: (null)
2012-02-16 11:59:11.298 FBFun[2330:207] Got Facebook Photo:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 803
    }
}
```

I have used following code, and it is working...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/USER_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_ID/photos"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"img1" ofType:@"jpg"];
nsstring *accessToken = @"AAACWZA..............................................Ts28iSOhGoOhe9qAgpZCL7AZDZD";
[request addData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dataForKey:@"image1"] forKey:@"file"];
[request setPostValue:@"Testing App For iPhone, please don't comment..." forKey:@"message"];
[request setPostValue:accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```