# What does the number refer to in link

Tags: ios, facebook

I am looking at old posts to try and figure out what's wrong with the hackbook example at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook .

In this post, [Post image to facebook using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991687/post-image-to-facebook-using-graph-api) , it seems that his problem was 117795728310/photos" instead of me/photos

What does 117795728310 refer to?  I'm assuming it's not his app id.  If it's his user id, where can I find out what mine is?

Thanks,
Mich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths of the open graph usually start with the id of the object and then it's connections.

For example: *[6708787004/feed](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=6708787004/feed)* will return the feed for the South Park page.

The id can be replaced with a "username", so the above example is the same as "[southpark/feed](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=southpark/feed)".
And "me/feed" is the same as "YOUR_USER_ID/feed"

You can get your id in all kind of ways, it will be easier to just check ["/me" in the graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me).

The id you posted is not of a user but a page ([graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=117795728310))

Comment: So if I'm writing a facebook app where the user will be logged into facebook already, me/photos should suffice instead of substituting 3294373360797/photos if I want to post a photo with the app on facebook?  If that's not why Hackbook doesn't work to post an image, I'm thinking the problem is that they never set permissions for uploading photos.

Comment: If you want to post an image to the user's photos then yes "me/photos" should do it, but as you wrote you'll need the required permission.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like a User ID.

Go to http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=91532827198 to see how you get yours